# Access remote VPN network from internal LAN

Tags: networking, vpn

I want to achieve the following:

[image]

Currently, I have setup a successful VPN connection using Wireguard between rPi A and B. On rPiA to access Router A network I issued: ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev zzzwg0. So I can ping 192.168.2.xxx from rPi A trough VPN connection. The question is: it would be possible to setup a static route on Router B to rPiA to enable access to the Router A network? If yes, what other iptable rules are needed on rPi A?

Comment: "Is it possible" depends on can you configure static routes on both of your routers. If not, then you need to configure those routes in the clients instead. There is no other requirements for iptables than to allow forwarded packets to pass.

Comment: I am using OpenWRT(LEDE) and Ubiquiti USG so I can. All suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: So what is the problem then?

Comment: I haven't done this before. On router I tried to set ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.50, but it's not working. Maybe there is need for more iptable rules on rPi A.

Comment: *Router B* needs to have the route *192.168.2.0/24 via rpiA* and *Router A* need to have the route *192.168.1.0/24 via rpiB*. *Random client* should have an address within 192.168.1.0/24 network.

Comment: I did, but the request doesn't go trough rPiA: $ traceroute 192.168.2.30
traceroute to 192.168.2.30 (192.168.2.30), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.50 (192.168.1.50)  38.677 ms  5.942 ms  2.042 ms ...